# Last tag border is broken in the hot questions list

Tags: bug, android-app, hot-questions

For hot question with many (or long name length) tags, right edge of the last tag is not visible:

> [image]

> [image]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1635123498b3d)

Comment: No repro Google Pixel.